# How can I copy bucket content cross region by using lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

How can I copy content from bucket in Virginia to bucket in Ireland by lambda function?

I am trying create lambda function in Virginia:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3();
s3.copyObject({
    Bucket: 'my-bucket-in-ireland',
    CopySource: 'my-bucket-in-virginia' + '/' + 'myKey.zip',
    Key: 'myKey.zip'
}, function (err, data) {
    // further handling logic goes here
});
```

But I got an error:

```
"The authorization header is malformed; the region 'us-east-1' is wrong; expecting 'eu-west-1'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the AWS signature calculation. I think the s3 client is using the region of the lambda function (us-east-1). But I think for the purpose of signature calculation, it is expecting the region to be the region of the destination bucket (eu-west-1). Can you try to pass a region to the s3 client and see if the signature is accepted?

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3({region: 'eu-west-1'});
```